# How to xmlstarlet on multiple files and append the output?

Tags: xml, linux, unix, xmlstarlet

I am using CSH Shell.

My Current Working xmlstarlet command (does an xmlstarlet operation on a single file and the result is pasted in an output text file):

*xmlstarlet sel -t -m '//RESULT_STEP' -v '@time_stamp' -o '|' -v '@step_name' --nl Report1.xml > /scratch/rys/view_storage/out.txt*

Now I need to this on multiple files Report1.xml and Report2.xml and store the appended result in an output file like above.

Is it possible to do this with xmlstarlet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd use your shell to do it. Example for bash:

```
{
  for xmlfile in Report1.xml Report2.xml
  do
    xmlstarlet sel ... "$xmlfile"
  done
} > .../out.txt
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you. But, this doesn't seem to work on CSH shell.

Comment: Of course it doesn't. Like I said, it works for bash. Use csh's iteration mechanism on csh.

Comment: Thanks. The below worked:

foreach xmlfile ( ResultReport1.xml ResultReport2.xml )
xmlstarlet sel -t -m '//RESULT_STEP' -v '@time_stamp' -o '|' -v '@step_name' --nl "$xmlfile" >> /scratch/rys/view_storage/outroo2.txt
end

Answer (score 1):

Just run the command on both files:

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -m '//RESULT_STEP' -v '@time_stamp' -o '|' -v '@step_name' --nl Report1.xml Report2.xml > /scratch/rys/view_storage/out.txt
```

Simple example:

```
echo "<a p='1'/>" > a.xml
echo "<b p='2'/>" > b.xml
xmlstarlet sel -t -m '/' -c '/' a.xml b.xml
```

results in: `<a p="1"/><b p="2"/>` and

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -m 'node()' -v '@p' a.xml b.xml
```

results in: `12`